# xfce Power Manager not running xflock4 correctly

Tags: archlinux, xfce, screen-lock

I'm having some problems getting the XFCE Power Manager to lock using `physlock`. When I set the Lock Screen on Lid Close action, upon opening my laptop lid I'm presented with an alternate lock screen, and after entering my password I get the error `None of the screen lock tools ran successfully, the screen will not be locked.`

[image: error]

However when I manually run `xflock4` from a terminal emulator, `physlock` is correctly used.

The relevant xfconf `LockCommand` setting is thus:

```
➜  ~ xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -v
physlock
```

And my power manager settings are this:

[image: this]

`physlock` was correctly working in the past using these settings, but as this stopped working some months ago, I'm afraid I won't be much help in narrowing down what triggered the initial change.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1568473/863965